# Mix: How do I reference user accounts in JS

Tags: web3js, dapp-development, mix

In Mix I can JS reference contracts with `contracts['name']`.  How do I reference the user accounts?

Answer (score 1):

You have web3.js available in Mix-IDE, so in the JS console you can use functions like

```
web3.eth.accounts
```

as usual.

The only other JS object that Mix exposes is **contracts**, as you can see in at [official wiki page](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Mix:-The-DApp-IDE)

> Note that Mix exposes the following objects into the global window
>   context:
>
> - **web3** - Ethereum JavaScript API
> - **contracts** - A collection of contract objects. A key to the collection
>     is the contract name. A value is an object with the following
>     properties:
>
>   - *contract* - Contract object instance (created as in web3.eth.contract)
>   - *address* - Contract address from the last deployed state (see below)
>   - *interface* - Contract ABI
>
> Check the JavaScript API Reference for further information.

Comment: I was thinking more of how Mix must somewhere have a {name:address} object so I could reference something like user[name] instead of having to write up a separate registry.

Comment: I see, but just consider that name/address associations are configurations you can find in the .mix JSON file, they are for the IDE and they are not intended to be used as a reference in your ÐApp code. In any case, I usually use an account.js file where I store my name/address associations, and then I load that file every time.

Answer (score 0):

in your .mix json there is effectively the name of the users
so a way to access them would be through that json, under the "states" key:

```
"states": [
                {
                        "accounts": [
                                {
                                        "address": "38f388fadf4a6a35c61c3f88194ec5ae162c8944",
                                        "balance": {
                                                "unit": 10,
                                                "value": "1"
                                        },
                                        "name": "user1",
                                        "secret": "cb73d9408c4720e230387d956eb0f829d8a4dd2c1055f96257167e14e7169074"
                                },
                                {
                                        "address": "3146577c741c31cc0b6479e5bef092bb8fe697d3",
                                        "balance": {
                                                "unit": 10,
                                                "value": "1"
                                        },
                                        "name": "bruce",
                                        "secret": "eebff1dce9aee5b5c056b4f61587f2861a8525e6fe3edf4584f38b41625a92cf"
                                },
                                {
                                        "address": "5833ebb3c3bedb9cce26db8b6b7290253d575b4e",
                                        "balance": {
                                                "unit": 10,
                                                "value": "1"
                                        },
                                        "name": "client2",
                                        "secret": "996e9abacf39a84154dcfaf9e5b3327c1c3fd5d15479a881c9f97fe7b6026adc"
                                },
                                {
                                        "address": "6d2f207b43241f609d2881bd3acbea70e2bcd698",
                                        "balance": {
                                                "unit": 10,
                                                "value": "1"
                                        },
                                        "name": "client1",
                                        "secret": "856124598b54a0c75f60e5d40c50c4dfba38034f4dca4d95e22fda6e1ce2802d"
                                }
                        ],
```